# "Spam" in an actual answer

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, spam

I just noticed this review audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5450522

And it shows an answer that, on the surface, looks totally reasonable, included below for <10K users. (The "MDB Repair Kit" is a link to the product's site):

> To repair a corrupt .mdb database of MS Access, one can try Compact
>   and Repair feature of MS Access. It repairs corrupt database and makes
>   it accessible for database users. Other than this one can also use
>   import feature of MS Access that helps database users import their
>   corrupt database to a new database file.
>
> If both these solutions fail to fix this corruption,
>
> Then one must check some third-party access database repair or
>   recovery software. I would like to suggest MDB Repair Kit software
>   here to repair corrupt .mdb and .accdb files. One can check its free
>   demo version before buying its full version.
>
> Hope this would be helpful.

Now, the question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, and it was deleted a few days ago. That being said, the answer provides two normal ways of solving the problem, and provides a link to a commercial product that also does so (the user has since been deleted, so its hard to say if he is affiliated or if this is repeat behavior). The OP even *asked* for a commercial product recommendation!

It seems that this is borderline spam at best, and I would likely have failed the audit if I didn't notice that it was a deleted question. It raised my "spam" signal, but when reading it, it seemed like a decent answer to a bad question.

Can this be removed from the audit list?

As an aside, it would be nice if you could challenge audits you *pass* (like this one for me) in addition to those you fail as have been suggested previously. We really need a human factor in these...

Comment: If the question asks for recommendations, then it may need to be closed. Posts like these are picked automatically, which means there is always going to be some borderline posts that are used for audits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I totally agree with the closure (and deletion). If anything, it should be improved and put on SuperUser. My question is why a Spam flag was accepted on this answer.

Comment: If the *user account* has been deleted as well, then it was most likely a user that *solely posted to promote the product*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point, especially considering the recency of the deletion (of course, they don't show that in the audit screen).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is definitely spam. There's no "borderline" about it. It definitely should **not** be migrated to Super User. In fact they probably posted the same question and answer to Super User already and that would have been deleted as spam at around the same time.

The question was posted by one account just so it could be answered with the spam by the second account. We see this all the time and not just on Stack Overflow.

The spammers try this because they think it's less detectable - which is where they are right - up to a point. However we do usually spot it sooner or later.

It's the perfect audit question and answer and should be retained.

For those with less than 10K rep here's a screen shot:

[image]

Note the following:

- The question is asking for a **commercial** tool for recovering the data. As such it should be closed any way.
- It's clearly not a programming problem - there's no code nor any indication that it's the OP's program that's trying to open the database.
- The answer reads like an advert.

Comment: A very interesting tactic.Just reading the answer, and even the question, what screams "Spam" about this to you? In context what you are saying definitely makes sense, but I would like to get better at spotting these right away, because it definitely fooled me.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - the fact that the question is asking about Access database recovery and the only answer was a spam answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the insight. I'll add those to my "thinks to check for context" when reviewing in the future.

Comment: I should also point out that this was part of a large, concerted effort to spam these products across the site. Almost all of them got through review and were still alive on the site when we came across them, so their spam tactic was working. In fact, the posts of this spam ring are still being approved: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5438278 http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5435546

Comment: @BradLarson Wow, those are really hard to see, especially off the first posts queue (where you don't get to see the answer, assuming you got the question for review). Other than the explicitly off-topic nature, they put some work into that spam! Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: @ChrisF - this is not clear to me (forgive my ignorance). I can only see the excerpt of the answer above. Were the questioner and answerer the same (I don't believe so)? If they were different, what made it overwhelmingly spam? Could the answer have been salvaged by *removing* the part that named a product (i.e., *"I would like to suggest MDB Repair Kit..."*)?

Comment: @BradLarson hey, how come the question was NaN?

Comment: @jww  From what I can see here I suspect the overwhelmingness is only visible in the context of someone looking for it.  I have caught several spammers by checking the post history of anyone suggesting a 3rd party tool and found an answer history consisting of repeatedly recommending a single product.  If they were using new accounts for each post, I doubt I'd've caught on either and done anything beyond voting off topic.

Comment: Are we reviewers expected to do searches for products recommended by new accounts to see if they're part of a single post per account spam farm?  That seems like a lot more work than a typical review, and something that could be much more efficiently done with algorithmic help; eg showing a half dozen posts by new users for the same product and asking us to look at them collectively to decide if they should be nuked or not.

Comment: Do you not feel that it's not enough to have audits if people just come away confused? Surely it's better to have some hand-picked audits with explanatory text. I for one would have learned nearly nothing if I just failed this audit, but this post has taught me lots.

Comment: What about if the the spam question is a valuable question? The user is still bringing valuable content to the site, why would their intention matter? I can imagine that if they were repeatedly creating poor questions and answers it'd be a problem, but if it was enough to fool people, I feel like the question had value.

Comment: "It's the perfect audit question and answer and should be retained" - disagree. Recognizing this as spam is heavily dependend on the context, you would have to know that this is simply one of many posts advertising this product. It's always said that reviewers are supposed to review an individual post _without_ context. It's also AFAIK the consensus that posts should not be flagged (or approved) as spam if it's not clearly malicious, as an approved spam flag results in heavy penalties against the user. Thus you can hardly blame someone for not recognizing this as spam or VLQ.

Comment: @TankorSmash - the question won't be valuable. It's only been asked to provide the spurious reason for the spam answer.

Comment: @jww - I made it clear in my answer that there are two accounts involved here. The first only post dummy questions, the second posts spam answers. Yes you have to check a little deeper to confirm what's going on, but the pattern is there.

Comment: @l4mpi - You are presented with the question when reviewing answers so you can see the context and the fact that it's a crap question anyway. You know how many other answers there are (in this case none).

Comment: @ChrisF I can't see the question anymore as it's deleted. But if it's not from the same user, why should the question being good or bad and having other answers or not influence me flagging the _answer_ as spam? I would be a bit suspicious if both OP and the answerer were new users without rep, but I'd need a lot more context before deciding "this answer is clearly spam". Imagine coming upon this question in the wild while browsing SO; I'd have surely down- and closevoted the question as you say it's crap, but I would definitely not have flagged the answer.

Comment: @l4mpi I've added a screen shot of the offending question and answer and some notes.

Comment: I'm thinking "check out the free demo" ought to be a pretty big flag that it needs a closer look.

Comment: Not spam, IMO. Many people ask answers as part of their paid work, and an employer would be happy to buy a 100$ tool, if it safes two hours of work time.

Comment: @Kay - it is spam. If people are being paid to provide answers then that's even more likely to make it spam.

Comment: @ChrisF I know that devs can nuke specific revisions from the revision history. What if the spam part of the answer is removed and the old revision is nuked? That would leave behind a good-looking answer.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi - the devs are highly unlikely to nuke revisions for reasons of spam.