# Can't look back on review audit, what was wrong with it?

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just ran into [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5585723) with a deleted question, and for some reason I can't view the answer anymore.

The answer had step by step instructions in it, and did not appear to be spam. It wasn't a thank you, a question, a link, or a comment, so it didn't seem like fell into the low quality post categories. I marked it as Looks OK, and was surprised to find answer was actually a review audit.

I can't look back at the answer to see if I missed something, since doing so oddly shows only the question and not the answer, the reverse of what I was originally shown, so I have no idea if I was just mistaken in my first impression.

I don't know if someone else can view it, but I'd like to know what I missed. If anyone can see the answer, could you enlighten me on the issue?

Not sure if I should also tag this as a bug, since not being able to look back at a review audit seems like an issue to me.

Comment: You need to have 10k reputation to view deleted posts; only during the audit can you view it. The post was made *in concert with the question*; the question is off-topic but was made **just** so the spammer could post that as the answer.

Comment: Note that the answer included a `goo.gl` URL shortener link to the product, and both question and answer are actually off-topic (they could have been on-topic for SuperUser). These posts are part of a concerted effort to place subtle spam for a series of very dodgy products all over Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think this is a bad review question. The revision you were shown didn't have the spam link because it was already edited out. Also, both the OP and two users who answered were deleted, only part of which is visible from /review.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the information. Is there some way someone could tell me the contents of the answer? I didn't see a link at all. Edit: Ah, good to hear that I couldn't view it, I was really worried that I'd just missed it.

Comment: I had a similar problem, failing an audit on an answer that looked fine to me but that was to a deleted question. Looking back I have the same problem, I can't see the answer any more. My take-away from that was that if I really need to go back and look at it all again I probably spent too little time reviewing before deciding. It's interesting that I can go back and see the question but not the answer I reviewed though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the original post that was selected for the review audit.  Note that the user was destroyed, taking the post with it.

[image]

Be suspicious about posts like this in Review.  The original question was "How do I repair a corrupted RAR file" which is off-topic.  Off topic questions like this one tend to draw spam answers, and even though there's no spam link in the current revision, it references (without disclosing affiliation) a recovery tool.

This is another good reason to **never edit a spam post.**  There are already tools in the system to deal with spam links, and removing the spam link only makes it harder for moderators and reviewers to evaluate the post properly.

Comment: Mofi removed the spam link from this and the other spam post, a rather unhelpful move here.

Comment: Right.  Spam links are removed from the post anyway if it is spam-flag deleted, so redacting them with an edit is unnecessary.

Comment: And the edit made it all the harder to detect that this was part of the spam campaign too.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the information, it's relieving to hear that I couldn't see the link. Would this kind of reference without disclosure and without a link be flaggable under normal circumstances?

Comment: The real problem is the question, not the answer.  Note that, while it appears that the spammer made an effort to answer the question asked, it's more likely that he has learned that indiscriminately posting a bare link accomplishes nothing, and has made his copy/paste spam more palatable by adding an (obvious) procedure for running the Winrar repair.

Comment: As Martijn points out, this is part of a large, coordinated spam effort by an individual or group to promote their "Recovery Toolbox" products. The question was asked by an account created just to ask questions for their other spam accounts to answer. They have created dozens of these accounts over the last several weeks, and have figured out that reviewers will approve their spam if they post it to these artificial off-topic questions. They are hitting Super User, Stack Overflow, and Server Fault with these same patterns of questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

Only 10k+ users can view deleted posts; here the question was also deleted, as it was spam.

The answer you were presented with in its original revision read (as Markdown to prevent the link from working):

```
You can repair your corrupt RAR file manually.
You can repair your corrupt RAR file manually. It is not a big process, it involves very easy steps. The steps are:
Open WinRAR application

1. Click on file, and then select open  
2. A find archive window will be
    opened, select corrupt rar file from your system  
3. Click on open
    button  
4. Press Alt+R  
5. Repairing File Name.rar will be opened  
6. Click
    on browse to save repaired file at desired location  
7. Check Treat the
    corrupt archive as RAR box, and then click OK  
8. After corrupt RAR
    archive is repaired, click on close.

If your file is highly corrupted and you need to use software then you can use additional software. You can use recovery toolbox for RAR. You can find it here http://goo.gl/KPPnmT  also there’s some information about such threads.
```

This is spam posted in concert with the (blatantly off-topic) question:

> ### How to repair damaged RAR file?
>
> I’ve got a damaged RAR file. I’ve got no idea how it happened. Week ago it was OK. But now I can’t extract it. It says datacab04 is corrupted. How I can fix it?

A second spam answer was also deleted.

Spammers are currently [conducting a campaign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267583/spam-in-an-actual-answer) creating what look like genuine questions and answers, but by using goog.le links are attempting to hide their activities.

This may be a difficult audit item, but at the same time, by failing the audit, you are now aware that this type of spam is being posted.

Comment: @gnat: not quite yet. And I'm willing to bet that the 'tools' have a few extra functions when installed you didn't quite expect or would approve of. I found several dozens of website domains and tool names that look suspiciously the same.  And the posts are *still* off-topic.