# Why was this closed as "spam or nonsense"?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage

Today I received an audit... I'll post the question URL here, though it is deleted (maybe moderators can still see it) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414360/cannont-compact-and-repair-the-database-access-2010

Audit URL: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9515451

The question text was:

> I have Access 2010 and want to compact and repair the database.
>
> I get this error message (this is translated, so it is not the exact words):
>
> "Cannont compact and repair the database. You may not have permission to the folder where the database reside. You must have full permission to the database folder to be able to compact and repair the database. Contact the system administrator for more information."
>
> The only information I have found on this matter is for Access 2003, and it was related to user permissions in the database. And in Access 2010 there is no user permissions anymore.
>
> Is the problem related to permissions on the server (the database file is located on a server (not Sharepoint)). Since the user can open the database I guess she have permission to create files (the .laccdb-file is created when the database is opened).
>
> I am lost here. Can anyone help me?

There were a few comments on the question from other users, and they seemed like reasonable suggestions... anyway, I said it looked OK, after which I got the "Stop! Look and Listen!" alert, where I was told that the post was removed by Community on 12 September for being "spam or nonsense."

This might not have been a great question, maybe not even a programming question, but I can't quite buy into the assessment that it was "spam or nonsense." I had thought that the audit tests were chosen by the higher-level moderators, sort of a curated set of tests, but now I am wondering, are they simply automatic, and if they are, how often are the tests themselves off base?

Comment: Yes, they are automatically chosen.  Posts marked and deleted as spam are especially likely to be chosen for "known-bad" audits.  That being said, it doesn't look like a great audit.  You might consider tagging this question [meta-tag:disputed-review-audits]

Comment: *how often are the tests themselves off base?* Often enough for this to be a regular topic on Meta, but not often enough that audits aren't useful. The way I understand it, questions that only have up votes, only have down votes, or were marked as spam are eligible audit questions. The idea is that if *everyone* agreed a question was good/bad/spam then an auditor that's paying attention would mark it the same way. Unfortunately, sometimes the community gets it wrong.

Comment: So, it's the triage queue? I would have voted unsalvagable because off-topic, not programming-related. I cannot see any indication that it was ever SPAM-flagged, but only a mod can say for sure.

Comment: @Deduplicator As I said in this meta post, it's arguable it is not a great question for SO, but what I am contesting is that it was deleted as spam, which it does not appear to have been. Maybe it should have been redirected to serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The context you are missing is that this was a question posted as a spam seed by a member of [this spam ring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269821/failed-a-tricky-review-question-not-sure-how-to-proceed/269868#269868). They intentionally post off topic questions like this so that they can provide answers linking to wherever they are hosting their file recovery spam products this month.

This one was deleted before their spam could be posted to it, but it had accumulated a spam flag from someone who knew their pattern of spam. That's why it was labeled as "possible spam" in review. No audits are selected by moderators, they are all determined by the system. This one became an audit when it had a spam flag against it validated by deletion.

You wouldn't know all that, but given how this question is off topic for the site, I still don't think that "Looks OK" is the appropriate response when presented with a question like that in review. A vote to close / close flag (or an "Unsalvageable" vote in triage) would seem to be a better way to handle that.

Comment: At a glance it doesn't look off-topic to me. I'd consider basic database management on-topic under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" rule. A similar MongoDB question [Reducing MongoDB database file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966687/reducing-mongodb-database-file-size) is open with 100+ upvotes and I wouldn't want to close it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: N.B. just because a question is still open and/or popular doesn't mean it's on-topic. If anything, many of the most highly scored posts tend to be wildly off-topic in my experience.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think most of the off-topic high scoring questions have been closed/locked by now. This question certainly doesn't fit the fun/subjective pattern many of them follow.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Didn't say it did :)