# Potential spam: Recovery Toolbox for Access

Tags: discussion, spam

Question: [Microsoft Office Access has detected corruption in this file. To try to repair the corruption, first make a backup copy of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805415/microsoft-office-access-has-detected-corruption-in-this-file-to-try-to-repair-t).

Oddly, the person asking the question joined Database SE and SO recently. But the person asked on SO.

More oddly, the person asking the question is `williamr86`. And the person answering is `geraldh88`. They joined within hours of one another.

I'm bringing it up in case its spam ring behavior, and the spam filters could be tuned.

Comment: Probably the same outfit as was behind this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267583/spam-in-an-actual-answer

Comment: @AndrewMedico - Yup, same group as here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269821/failed-a-tricky-review-question-not-sure-how-to-proceed/269868#269868 . Really clever and persistent spammers that know how to get their stuff through review on SO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Our spam blockers are largely fed by user flags and moderator actions. So in this case, I spam-flagged the questions, destroyed the users, and that should help out a bit. Naturally, both of them came in via TOR, so take that with a grain of salt.

Thanks for the heads up and don't be afraid to use those spam flags in the future. :)