# You approved obvious spam

Tags: support

I reviewd about 2 to 3 hours ago (3.12.2014 22:00 - 23:00) some late answers.

Then there were no more late answers to review (or I reviwed 20, I can't remember). But there was no message like "Stop! This was a test and you failed" or something.

Then I did something else, my browser crashed and I had to restart it.

Then I noticed that, it is after midnight and I could review some more. But then the message appeared:

> You approved obvious spam: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6379088 . Please do not do that again.
>   Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing.

If I visit the link, it says

> answer not found

and If I look in my activitys, I cannot find a review for "Attaching an MDF file without LDF file". I think I did not review this late answer, but maybe my browser did by reloading the page after the crash?

Does anyone know what just happened?
If I did something wrong, please tell me.

*Notice:* It's ok that I'am banned from reviewing. There are enough people that can do this, so I'am not asking for unbanning me.

Comment: That post is an obvious spam/advertisement from some SQL tool. It was an audit that was meant to make sure you were paying attention, and apparently you failed that audit. Moderators do manually ban users who fail egregious audits.

Comment: @Mysticial It wasn't an audit.  It was real spam that he really approved.

Comment: @Servy Oh you're right. Maybe mods get notified if a post that was approved in review later gets spam-deleted.

Comment: @Mysticial They already can see that.

Comment: OK. I was just confused because I cannot see the answer I failed to review and I cannot see it in my activitys and there was no message, so I had just no chance to see what the problem was. I will try to do a better review after the ban. Thanks

Comment: My related question has the text copy-pasted in (or at least, similar text): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267583/spam-in-an-actual-answer

Comment: "There are enought [sic] people that can do this" I wish more people could think like you do.

Comment: We really, really need this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you didn't fail an audit, but a moderator manually applied the ban after noticing what happened (you reviewed an actual spam post as "No Action Needed").

Please note that this is the work of a notorious, persistent [spam ring](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271257/potential-spam-recovery-toolbox-for-access) that keeps coming back. Flagging these correctly is important.

Comment: Yes, there is no system-generated message that says "You approved obvious spam" - it's always placed by a moderator.

Answer (score 5):

The link shows you reviewed it, and I've never heard of a refresh causing a review action to be taken (obviously a bug if it happened).

The post *was* obviously spam, so the message makes sense. Given the content of the message, its quite possible a mod manually banned you for approving the post, which also would explain the lack of a "STOP: Look and Listen!" message.

You should have flagged that post right away.