# Duff review audit?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

As much as this answer clearly did end up being deleted because of numerous random answers, we are told that [an altogether wrong answer is not a good enough reason to have it deleted from SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251393/3899908).

On [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6856581) (which ended up being an audit), my intention was simply to mark this review as **Looks OK** and then immediately flag (after a quick look at the user's answer record) for moderator attention with a custom reason - as there was a comment that the user had been posting random answers.

It was my belief that the answer had been incorrectly flagged as low quality when the moderator flag was needed.

Any thoughts? Am I just wrong in my assumptions, or have I been done good and proper?

PS: I was review banned as a result of failing this review audit, but I can deal with that!

Comment: It being accepted as spam fed it into the audit system, but its one that you wouldn't know was spam without the context (at least I wouldn't). Somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267583/spam-in-an-actual-answer

Comment: [The low-quality review audit system is broken](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275793/the-low-quality-review-audit-system-is-broken).

Comment: mmmmm... Duff...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've cleared the spam flag off that post. I glanced over the user's account and I saw absolutely nothing as far as patterns of "random answers" (whatever the hell that means) or spam-like behavior from that user. I honestly have no clue what that comment was on about. If I can't even figure it out at a quick glance, there's no way in hell we can expect a reviewer to catch on to it (I'm rather convinced it was just a bogus flag though).

Comment: In which case, can I be un-review banned please?!

Comment: @worldofjr Done.

Comment: Again: the audit system for the low-quality review queue is terribly broken and needs to be fixed. The answer in that audit looks perfectly fine.