# Timed out from review tasks - no visible answer of deleted question

Tags: bug, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

Earlier today I did some reviews. Unfortunately i got timed out for too many incorrect reviews. I remember having cast a few wrong review votes in the past - the one today though i feel was not my fault. The low quality post i was reviewing is the following: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8053785 - I hope the link works for everybody and is not just visible for me.

As you can see via the link or on the following image: the question has been deleted. I guess as a result of that the answer is not visible either.
[image]

I think I remember seeing that the question was deleted and I decided to review the answer none the less - it still could have been a valid answer. Unfortunately my review was apparently wrong! I am now not sure wether the answer should not have been displayed in the first place or if it was a valid review task. Was my review really wrong or did something else go wrong there - i can not rethink my decision since the answer is not visible.

**tl;dr**

- is it a bug showing answer to be reviewed of deleted questions?
- can the fact that the question got deleted impact the outcome of my review "score"
- it most definitely is a bug that i can not look at my wrong decision since the answer is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the answer you reviewed:

[image: Image of answer]

That answer was spam for a website (note the link), from a group that has been regularly posting this spam everywhere on the SE network. It was destroyed as spam, which made it an audit case. When you voted "Looks OK" on that, you failed that audit and triggered a 2-day review ban. Other audit failures preceded this.

The problem here is that if you don't have sufficient reputation to view deleted posts, you won't see that answer. I've [previously requested this capability for reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed), so that people can learn from their audit failures.

Comment: Okay, while I do not agree 100% with the statement that the answer was spam - at least that answers my question.

Comment: @luk2302 spammers can be pretty clever: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267583/spam-in-an-actual-answer

Comment: @luk2302 In your defense, the answer on its own isn't spam. It's only when considered in the context of being one of many group-based posts that it becomes spam. So there was no reasonable way for you to know it was spam. The system is imperfect, so sometimes we run into gotchas like this.

Comment: @TylerH: It looks slightly fishy, enough to look at the user / the full Q&A, especially as there was probably a warning banner. Which would immediately give all the data needed.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I've never found the "this post is possible spam!" banner to be at all relevant; it shows up more often in known-good review audits than anywhere else.